# Not able to use Google fonts in Flutter sliverappbar

Tags: flutter, google-fonts, flutter-sliverappbar

I am using Google Fonts in my app. I have successfully done so across my app but for some reason I cannot use it in SliverAppBar. The error I get is:

`The constructor being called isn't a const constructor.`

My code I am trying to change the font for is:

```
SliverAppBar(
          pinned: true,
          snap: false,
          floating: false,
          expandedHeight: 200.0,

          leading: new IconButton(
            color: Colors.black38,
            icon: new Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                  context,
                  '/');
            },
          ),

          backgroundColor: Globals().appBar,
          flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title:
            Text('Inventory', style: GoogleFonts.acme(color: Globals().white_text,fontSize: 20),) ,
            // Text('Inventory'),
            background: FittedBox(fit:BoxFit.cover,child: Image(image:AssetImage('images/bag.jpg'))),
          ),
        ),
```

If I the simple Text box you see in the code  `// Text('Inventory'),` then I don't have an issue. how do you use Google Fonts in the SliverAppbar?

Comment: Removing const from the FlexibleSpaceBar may work.

Answer (score 1):

So, I think that the google_fonts package class doesn't implement a const constructor, because, by default, it's going to do an HTTP Internet request for the font. This means that the font is loaded at RUNTIME, which means it can't be a const. Even if you turn that functionality off with "GoogleFonts.config.allowRuntimeFetching = false;", I don't think the package author intends for you to use it that way; hence no const constructor.

The only workaround for this is to just use the regular method of adding custom fonts without the google_fonts package. This is actually safer, since the font will be baked into your application and can safely be used without Internet. The only drawback would be that it will make your application larger.

Here is a link to the current method of adding custom fonts:

https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/fonts

Comment: This seems to be a link only answer.  It would be better to post the relevant information in your answer, in case the link disappears in the future.

Comment: I posted the link, because it would be better for them to look up the relevant information via search engine anyway; if I just copy-paste it here and it changes in the future, wouldn't both the answer and link be useless anyway? Flutter is still changing and if they edit that page, but my answer stays out-of-date, then I wouldn't be helping, but adding more to the confusion. If you want me to copy-paste the whole article, I can do that, but that seems unnecessary, because I could also just remove the link and the pertinent part of the message would still  be there. Let me know what you want.

Comment: @WhiteMage https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259